Is it ok to use bitcoin-lib.js from bitcoincore.tech for production?
There's a bitcoin-lib.js at bitcoincore.tech website, but from the code it is not clear which version is it? Master-branch? Stable?

As @paulmillr stated:

If your goal is absolute security, don't use any JS lib — including
bindings to native ones. Use low-level libraries & languages.


From bitcoinlib-js documentation:

The recommended method of using bitcoinjs-lib in your browser is
through browserify.

like this:
$ npm install bitcoinjs-lib browserify
$ npx browserify --standalone bitcoin -o bitcoinjs-lib.js <<< "module.exports = 
require('bitcoinjs-lib');"

and then compare it with https://bitcoincore.tech/apps/bitcoinjs-ui/lib/bitcoinjs-lib.js
